# MapboxDirections set origin and destination dynamically

Tags: javascript, navigation, geolocation, mapbox, directions

I want to set route multiple times on my map, based on some markers latitude and longitude.

`setOrigin()` and `setDestination()` works fine when called on map load:

```
var directions = new MapboxDirections({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
    });

map.addControl(directions,'top-left');

map.on('load',  function() {
    directions.setOrigin([12, 23]);
    directions.setDestinaion([11, 22]);
})
```

But when I call it later, for example, on map `moveend`, the origin input field is trying to resolve location forever, and I get infinite loop (there is loading icon in origin input, and console prints logs from `moveend` function forever)

**EDIT: added more info**

My code fragment

```
    mymap.on('moveend', async function () {
        if (old_zoom === mymap.getZoom()) {
            let coords = mymap.getCenter();
            console.log(coords);  // it is printed inifnitely, until Chrome crashes

            directions.setOrigin('19.969415,50.061824');
            directions.setDestination('19.9242978306511,50.0401092');
    });
```

I think it crashes, because when I set origin and destination, route is being displayed, and there is an animation that moves the map, so `moveend` event is triggered, and so on.

So I think the solution here will be to stop `MapboxDirections` from moving my map when route is generated, because my concept is to `setOrigin()` every time when user stops moving the map (origin point is always in center of map)

Comment: Can you add the code where you don't call it on map load? Also, would you like to have multiple routes displayed, or just change the currently displayed route?

Comment: @Moritz Hi, I added more info. I want only one route at a time, but It can be changed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the context! I would replace the event `moveend`

by `dragend` to make sue the map panning was intended. You could then re-set the directions object in the callback of `dragend`.

Please see the documentation here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:dragend